# Are there any good extensible language cross compilers?

Tags: compilation, cross-compiling, extensibility

I am working on a project right now, and I would greatly enjoy being able to extend a cross compiler to convert some code into other languages. For example, I might have an AST of some code, and I would like to pass that off to a cross compiler with the intended language and receive some code in the language specified in return.

So to sum it up: is there any extensible cross compiler that I can just give an AST or equivalent and receive code in return?

(I know about Haxe, but the compiler is not very extensible and I would prefer to not transpile)

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Look into [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/)

Comment: The Haxe compiler is actually pretty extensible with macros. I suggest you take a look at some [examples](https://code.haxe.org/category/macros/) and see if anything matches your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the decision to use [LLVM](https://llvm.org/) as the native compiler, and will write my own custom transpilers to other languages, as I could find no other decent option. If you would like to follow my project, head over to [Provalang](https://github.com/BSFishy/Provalang).